# Insert new row below a tapped row in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been trying to add a new row dynamically in a UITableView when the user taps on the row just above. There seem to be 2-3 other posts around this but am somehow not able to connect / leverage the same.

Following is my code. Could someone give me an idea please where I might be going wrong?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger rowsRequired = 0;

    if (section == 0) {
        rowsRequired = 1;
    }
    else {
        rowsRequired = [[self contents] count] + 1;
    }

    return rowsRequired;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:        (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CellType1 *cell1 = nil;
    CellType2 *cell2 = nil;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@“CellType1”];

        if (cell1 == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@“CellType1” owner:self options:nil];
            cell1 = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        return cell1;
    }
    else {
        cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@“CellType2”];

        if (cell2 == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@“CellType2” owner:self options:nil];
            cell2 = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        return cell2;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section];
        indexPath = newPath;

        [[self contents] insertNewRow:@“My New Row”];

        [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you check for `indexPath.section` but not for `indexPath.row==self.contents.count` when deciding whether to add a new row

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11... much appreciated. Tried out the same but somehow didnt work... the exception I get relates to inconsistency in number of rows, so I suspect my loading of the model is not happening correctly...

Comment: You should really use `dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath`. Also sounds like `insertNewRow` is perhaps not updating `self.contents`.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcKinnel ... Apologies for the late response but yes, my insertNewRow was what was indeed corrupting the data, so thats fixed now... Also, on the dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath method, if I use it instead of just dequeResuableCellWithIdentifier, the app throws an exception. I found that if am using a nib, then calling the method with the indexPath argument somehow doesn't work. However, if not loading a nob and directly using the UITableViewCell load using registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell", the indexPath function works!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to insert the new value in the array after the current index path value

```
 [contents insertObject:myObject atIndex:10];
```

Comment: Right! It's a good practice to always update tableview's datasource whenever you want to change what you wanna show.  And then reload table or insert a row with `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method of a tableview.